# How do I simulate 3000 dice rolls and count the number of times doubles are rolled? JAVA

Tags: java, dice

I'm new to the programming world so I'd deeply appreciate if any of you could help me become better at this. My goal for this program is to simulate 3000 dice rolls and count the number of times doubles are rolled for each of the different possible pairs of doubles using a while loop. The results should be printed out in a dialog box.

```
   Random random;
   random = new Random();
   diceRolls = 1;
   snakeEyes = 1;
   doubleTwos = 1;
   doubleThrees = 1;
   doubleFours = 1;
   doubleFives = 1;
   doubleSixes = 1;


   while (diceRolls <= finalDiceRoll) {
       int diceRolls = 1;
       int die1 = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
       int die2 = random.nextInt(6) + 1;


       if (die1 == 1 && die2 == 1){
           //snakeEyes = snakeEyes + 1;    
           snakeEyes++;

       }
       else if (die1 == 2 && die2 == 2 ) {
           doubleTwos++;
       }
       else if (die1 == 3 && die2 == 3) {
           doubleThrees++;
       }
       else if (die1 == 4 && die2 == 4) {
           doubleFours++;
       }
       else if (die1 == 5 && die2 == 5) {
           doubleFives++;
       }
       else if (die1 == 6 && die2 == 6) {
           doubleSixes++;
       }
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You rolled snake eyes " + snakeEyes + " times\nYou rolled double twos " + doubleTwos + " times\nYou"
                                     + " rolled double threes " + doubleThrees + " times\nYou rolled double fours " + doubleFours + " times\nYou"
                                     + " rolled double fives " + doubleFives + " times\nYou rolled double sixes " + doubleSixes + " times");

}
```

The issue i'm having here is that the results i'm getting from the program don't seem "plausible". For example, out of 3000 dice rolls, I get 1 pair of each double. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you already have each pair of double initialized to 1.
Do you get no pair of doubles from the program?

Comment: You show the dialog after each dice roll. You have to click it away for 3000 times to get your final results.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `showMessageDialog` outside of the while loop and increment the `diceRolls` variable. Initialize all other integer variables with 0.
A better (cleaner and shorter) approach would be to use a two-dimensional array or a map.

```
Random random = new Random();
int snakeEyes = 0;
int doubleTwos = 0;
int doubleThrees = 0;
int doubleFours = 0;
int doubleFives = 0;
int doubleSixes = 0;
int diceRolls = 1;
while (diceRolls <= 3000) {
    int die1 = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
    int die2 = random.nextInt(6) + 1;

    if (die1 == 1 && die2 == 1) {
        snakeEyes++;
    } else if (die1 == 2 && die2 == 2) {
        doubleTwos++;
    } else if (die1 == 3 && die2 == 3) {
        doubleThrees++;
    } else if (die1 == 4 && die2 == 4) {
        doubleFours++;
    } else if (die1 == 5 && die2 == 5) {
        doubleFives++;
    } else if (die1 == 6 && die2 == 6) {
        doubleSixes++;
    }
    diceRolls++;
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You rolled snake eyes " + snakeEyes + " times\nYou rolled double twos " + doubleTwos + " times\nYou"
        + " rolled double threes " + doubleThrees + " times\nYou rolled double fours " + doubleFours + " times\nYou"
        + " rolled double fives " + doubleFives + " times\nYou rolled double sixes " + doubleSixes + " times");
```

The above-mentioned shorter version:

```
Random random = new Random();
int[] doubled = new int[6];

for (int diceRolls = 0; diceRolls < 3000; diceRolls++) {
    int die1 = random.nextInt(6);
    int die2 = random.nextInt(6);

    if (die1 == die2)
        doubled[die1]++;
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You rolled snake eyes " + doubled[0] + " times\nYou rolled double twos " + doubled[1] + " times\nYou"
        + " rolled double threes " + doubled[2] + " times\nYou rolled double fours " + doubled[3] + " times\nYou"
        + " rolled double fives " + doubled[4] + " times\nYou rolled double sixes " + doubled[5] + " times");
```

Answer (score 1):

Few changes you have to make in your code,

**1.** Initialize all your variables by `0`.

**2.** change `while-loop` condition to

```
 while (diceRolls <= finalDiceRoll)  // hoping that finalDiceRoll = 3000
```

**3** remove `int diceRolls = 1;` from `while-loop` and add `diceRolls++;` at end of `while-loop`.

**4.** Put your `JOptionPane` outside `while-loop`. if not you have to close 3000 time your `JOptionPane` dailog.

After applying these changes to your code you will learn what have you done wrong and your code will run fine.

Answer (score 0):

The counting logic should go as follows:

```
doubleTwos = 0;
doubleThrees = 0;
doubleFours = 0;
doubleFives = 0;
doubleSixes = 0;

finalDiceRoll = 3000;
int diceRolls = 0;
while (diceRolls < finalDiceRoll) {
    ++diceRolls;
```

With any message *after* the loop.

With an array you may save typing:

```
int[] doubleCounts = new int[6]; // By 0 based dice values
for (int i = 0; i < finalDiceRoll; ++i) {
    int die1 = random.nextInt(6); // With dice values 0-5
    int die2 = random.nextInt(6);

    if (die1 == die2) {
       ++doubleCounts[die1];
    }
}
int snakeEyes = doubleCounts[0];
int doubleTwos = doubleCounts[1];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify. Eliminate duplications. Don't use multiple variables when you can use an array.

```
int[] doubles = new int[7]; // make the index the number rolled (ignore index 0)
int diceRolls = 0;
while (diceRolls++ < 3000) {
  int die1 = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
  int die2 = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
  if (die1 == die2)
       doubles[die1]++;
}
String output = "";
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
    output += "You rolled double " + i + "'s " + doubles[i] + " times\n";

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, output);
```

That's all you need.

Comment: An instance of `StringBuilder` would be the icing on the cake.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz I was trying to keep it simple for a beginner. It's only 6 iterations of concatenating short strings, so `+` is good enough.